# Riemann integrability and Riemann sums

Tags: integration, riemann-integration, riemann-sum

If we don't use improper integrals, $f(x)=1/\sqrt{x}$ is not Riemann-integrable on $[0,1]$ because only bounded functions are Riemann-integrable. Does that mean that there exists a tagged partition of $[0,1]$ and a corresponding Riemann sum that doesn't converge (to 2) for $f(x)$? (I wasn't able to find one)

Comment: Before Riemann sums converging to 2 or not, no upper Riemann sum of the function is even defined.

Comment: Thanks @Did! Indeed.

Comment: I am going to post a separate follow-up question on the difference between Riemann integral and HK integral - I am confused about that $\delta$ becoming $\delta(x_i)$ and the difference it really makes.

Comment: If you do, please add which introductory texts to HK you have read, and why precisely these left you unsatisfied. I am mentioning this because there are some very good texts out there...

Comment: @Did - can you recommend texts? The one I have in mind is in French by Jean-Pierre Demailly from Université Joseph Fourier Grenoble I. Somewhere in here: https://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/~demailly/books.html, this one to be precise: https://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/~demailly/manuscripts/kurzweil.pdf.

Comment: If you are interested, my follow-up question is here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2400712/difference-between-riemann-and-kh-integrals.

Comment: @Did - any reference you could recommend? You hinted that you knew about very good texts.

Comment: Unfortunately (!), I would definitely recommend Demailly's text.

Comment: Is Demailly known in the English speaking world??

Comment: ?? You should check a CV of the guy one day...

Comment: I knew he was "big" in France, but I didn't realize if he was also "big" outside of the country :-)

Answer (score 2):

If you'd like to see a specific example, here's one. For an arbitrary partition of $[0,1]$, let $[0,x_1]$ be its leftmost subinterval, where $0<x_1<1$ (of course). Then for any $N>1$, the point $x_1^{*}=\frac{x_1^2}{N^2}$ is in $[0,x_1]$, and the first term in the corresponding Riemann sum will be
$$f(x_1^{*})\Delta x_1=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x_1^2/N^2}}\cdot x_1=N,$$
which can be arbitrarily large if we let $N\to+\infty$. Since the rest of the terms are nonnegative, we see that Riemann sums are unbounded and don't have a limit.

Comment: Very nice! Thanks!

Comment: So, in the case of the KH integral, this particular partition could be eliminated by choosing a gauge carefully? In the case of Riemann-integrability, I can't disallow this partition you are showing, but in the case of KH-integrability, I can choose a gauge that would eliminate this partition (and in fact, have all Riemann sums on finer gauges also converge, as required)?

Comment: @Frank: Yes, that's the idea. To be honest, I'm not so well-familiar with HK-integrals, so I can't say much here. But it looks like you've gotten some good advice in the other thread.

Comment: Indeed. KH integral looks to me so far as an integral that gives you more freedom (via a _gauge_ function $\delta(x_i)$ instead of a constant $\delta$), so that you can disallow tagged partitions that don't "play nice" with the local behavior of the function you want to integrate. I would be curious to see a function that's KH-integrable but not Riemann-integrable _and_ not "reachable" as an improper integral, i.e. to see how KH is more powerful than Riemann + improper.