# Difference between Riemann and KH integrals

Tags: integration, riemann-integration

To go from the definition of the Riemann integral ($f$ is Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$ if there exists a real $A$ such that $\forall \epsilon >0, \exists \delta>0$ such that $\forall D=\{([a_i,a_{i+1}],x_i)\}$ tagged partition of $[a,b]$ $h_i=a_{i+1}-a_i < \delta \implies |S_D(f) - A| < \epsilon$, where $S_D(f)$ is the Riemann sum on $D$) to the definition of the KH integral, all we do is replace the constant $\delta$ by a ("variable") gauge function $\delta(x_i)$.

However, the definition of the Riemann integral allows arbitrary tagged partitions, as long as $h_i<\delta$. Isn't that as flexible as the definition of the KH integral ($h_i < \delta(x_i)$)? For a given $\epsilon$, we can first find a tagged partition that will make the Riemann sums converge, then take $\delta = max({h_i})$ and satisfy the Riemann definition? In other words, any tagged partition that is allowed in the definition of the KH integral also seems to be allowed in the definition of the Riemann integral, and making the $\delta$ variable doesn't seem to be "essential". Of course, I am missing something. What am I missing?

Comment: That KH allows to vary the jauge, that is, to replace a fixed level $\delta$ by a function $\delta:[a,b]\to(0,+\infty)$.

Comment: @Did - yes I see that. How does it matter, since in any case, arbitrary tagged partitions are already allowed in the Riemann integral definition (in particular, tagged partitions with variable steps are allowed already)?

Comment: It does matter: Riemann asks more since it allows more partitions.

Comment: I certainly don't doubt it matters - I'm trying to understand how. I am not understanding how "more" partitions would be allowed on any one side, since I am only required to exhibit some $\delta$, I can choose $\delta$, so I could choose any partition I want first, then "retrieve" a suitable $\delta$ or a $\delta(x_i)$, in both cases. In fact, the more I think about it, the less I see the actual difference (again, I'm sure there is of course one). I'm about to really _learn_ something here :-)

Comment: My advice: Show in details that $f(x)=1/\sqrt{x}$ is KH-integrable on $(0,1)$.

Comment: In the case of $1/\sqrt{x}$ on $[0,1]$, I can use the partition with $a_i=(i/N)^2$ and $x_i=((i+1/2)/N)^2$, find the $\delta$ that corresponds, and satisfy the Riemann definition, can I not? Maybe that's my real problem: this particular tagged partition doesn't seem to be disallowed by the Riemann integral definition.

Comment: Ah, so in fact what you are missing is the meaning of Riemann-integrability. Recall that one asks that the Riemann sums for **every** partition of mesh at most $\delta$ are such that so and so, not only those of a partition one would choose carefully.

Comment: Yes - I had seen that. And for the KH integrability, we require *every* partition of mesh at most $\delta(x_i)$. Maybe I just need to think about that harder.

Comment: Indeed, hence KH-integrability condition is **more** lax.

Comment: See my comment under the response by zipirovich in the other thread. I think I'm starting to get it, slowly.